# Ignore certificate errors in headless Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use `WebDriver` 3.12. I have two instances from application, one with invalid and one with valid SSL certification. Testsuite is working correctly with one of valid certificate. `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag is ignored in headless mode in `ChromeDriver` 2.40. I tried `--acceptInsecureCerts` flag too, but has same effect.
I initialize driver variable as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs).addArguments("--start-maximized").addArguments("--acceptInsecureCerts").setHeadless(true));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setAcceptInsecureCerts. See java doc here for further info https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setAcceptInsecureCerts-boolean-

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code snippet, which works for me:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");

DesiredCapabilities crcapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
crcapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
crcapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
crcapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);

System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_LOG_PROPERTY, "C:\\Path\\TO\\chromedriver.log");
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, "C:\\Path\\TO\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeDriverService service = null;
try {
    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .withVerbose(true)
            .build();
    service.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),crcapabilities);

driver.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
driver.quit();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icons/favicon-red.ico" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icons/icon-red.png" />
  <title>self-signed.badssl.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  <style>body { background: red; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <h1 style="font-size: 12vw;">
    self-signed.<br />badssl.com
  </h1>
</div>



</body></html>
```

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
```